# COUNT with IF FROM DISTINCT values MySQL

Tags: mysql, count, distinct-values

I am trying to calculate the how many users are female and how many male, after doing DISTINCT on the UserID

```
SELECT
COUNT(IF("Gender" = 'female', 1, NULL)) as Ufemale,
COUNT(IF("Gender" = 'male', 1, NULL)) as Umale
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM user_stats where Year='2019' and Account='P') as UID
```

If I execute the

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM user_stats where Year='2019' and Account='P'
```

It returns the unique UserID. However, if I combine it with count gender part, it returns Zero.

Here is how the values looks like

```
UserID            |  Gender
-----------------------------
2018359084885123  |  male
1925823664195671  |  female
2033134076795519  |
2122445674469149  |  female
2315129265210413  |  female
2018359084885123  |  male
2122445674469149  |  female
```

And the aim is to show

```
Ufemale  |  Umale
-------------------
   3     |    1
```

Comment: You could change `SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM user_stats where Year='2019' and Account='P'` to `SELECT DISTINCT UserID, gender FROM user_stats where Year='2019' and Account='P'`

Comment: *"I am trying to calculate the how many users are female and how many male"* then the expected result would be 4 and 2 based on the current data? Also your example data is missing the year and Account column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**Tables**

```
drop table if exists test;

create table test (userid bigint, gender char(6));

insert into test values
(2018359084885123,'male')
,(1925823664195671,'female')
,(2033134076795519, null)
,(2122445674469149,'female')
,(2315129265210413,'female')
,(2018359084885123,'male')
,(2122445674469149,'female');
```

**Query**

```
select
    sum(case when gender = 'female' then 1 else 0 end) as ufemale,
    sum(case when gender = 'male' then 1 else 0 end) as umale
from
(select distinct userid, gender from test) x
```

**Result**

```
ufemale umale
3       1
```

Example: https://rextester.com/JLQ19855

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Gender` column in the results of the subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM user_stats where Year='2019' and Account='P'
```

as you may think. 
What you are doing is comparing 2 strings: `"Gender"` and `'female'` which are obviously not equal so this:

```
IF("Gender" = 'female', 1, NULL)
```

returns `NULL` and `COUNT(NULL)` returns `0`.
Where is the `Gender` column?
Is it in `user_stats` table or in another table like `Users`?
If it is in `user_stats` then you need to write the query like this:

```
select
  sum(t.gender = 'female') ufemale,
  sum(t.gender = 'male') umale
from (
  select distinct userid, gender 
  from user_stats 
  where Year='2019' and Account='P'
) t
```

If it is in the `users` table then you will need a join first:

```
select
  sum(u.gender = 'female') ufemale,
  sum(u.gender = 'male') umale
from (
  select distinct userid, gender 
  from user_stats 
  where Year='2019' and Account='P'
) t inner join users u
on u.userid = t.userid
```